# Skip AJAX function if the same request is being made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have my AJAX request inside a JavaScript function. using the setInterval function the AJAX function is executed every 5000ms.

I was wondering if there was a way to check if the previous AJAX call is still processing so I don't have multiple AJAX requests the same.

Here is my code:

```
function getData(fields){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { fields: fields },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {                                                                                       
        if (json) {
            // We have a response
        }   
    });
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    getPosts(fields);
}, 2000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var req;
```

Make a variable we can access outside of the scope of the function.

```
function getData(fields) {
    req = $.ajax({...});
```

Assign the variable to the ajax request

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (req.state() == 'resolved' && req.state() !== 'pending') {
        getPosts(fields);
    }
});
```

Detect the `.state()`

Comment: You might want to check for `!== "pending"` instead...just in case it fails

Comment: Excellent! It works.  The only problem was req.state() was undefined as the function hadn't executed, therefor req.state() would be undefined. I just added the function onload to fix that!  Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Ian I haven't encountered that issue yet, but I've added it for peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var getDataRequest = null;
function getData(fields) {
    if (getDataRequest !== null) {
        return;
    }
    getDataRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { fields: fields },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json) {
                // We have a response
            }
            getDataRequest = null;
        }
    });
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    getPosts(fields);
}, 2000);
```